# How to prevent android to select Bluetooth A2DP route when bluetooth device is connected

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I'm using MediaRouter (from v7 support library) and programmatically select route for audio to my specific device route, but when some bluetooth A2DP device is connected, Android automatically selects route associated with that bluetooth device.

How can I prevent it from switching from my already selected and desired route?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984015/how-to-capture-or-reroute-navigation-voice-stream/13991953#13991953 for a suggestion of how to do this (may or may not work on your device). You could also try calling the `AudioService` [`setBluetoothA2dpOn` method](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/base/tree/media/java/android/media/AudioService.java?h=aosp-new/master#n2370) in the same way, but it might be a bit trickier since it's non-static.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like there is no way to do it so far.

Auto switching to the Bluetooth A2DP route is hardcoded into Android framework [MediaRouter class](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaRouter.java#L21)

> This will select the active BT route if there is one and the current   selected route is the default system route, or if there is no selected route yet.

So, if your current route is default one, BT A2DP route will be automatically selected. It is possible to listen to [onRouteSelected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouter.Callback.html#onRouteSelected(android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter,%20android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo)) callback and select your default route back.